# XML with several levels to XML with one level using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSL and I have two questions regarding several child elements.

I have the following structure in my XML document:

```
<root>
  <levelOne>
  <entry1>Test1</entry1>
  <entry2>Test2</entry2>
    <levelTwo>
      <entry3>Test3</entry3>
      <entry4>Test4</entry4>
      <levelThree>
        <entry5>Test5</entry5>
        <entry6>Test6</entry6>
      </levelThree>
    </levelTwo>
  </levelOne>
  <levelOne>
  <entry1>Test1</entry1>
  <entry2>Test2</entry2>
    <levelTwo>
      <entry3>Test3</entry3>
      <entry4>Test4</entry4>
      <levelThree>
        <entry5>Test5</entry5>
        <entry6>Test6</entry6>
      </levelThree>
    </levelTwo>
  </levelOne>
  <!-- etc. -->
</root>
```

My XSL looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="root">
<resultlistEntries>
    <xsl:for-each select="levelOne">
        <entry1><xsl:value-of select="entry1"/></entry1>
        <entry2><xsl:value-of select="entry2"/></entry2>
        <!-- address child elements? -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</resultlistEntries>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want entry 3, 4, 5, 6 etc. to be one the same level in my output XML document. So the expecting output should look like this:

```
<root>
  <levelOne>
  <entry1>Test1</entry1>
  <entry2>Test2</entry2>
  <entry3>Test3</entry3>
  <entry4>Test4</entry4>
  <entry5>Test5</entry5>
  <entry6>Test6</entry6>
  <entry1>Test1</entry1>
  <entry2>Test2</entry2>
  <entry3>Test3</entry3>
  <entry4>Test4</entry4>
  <entry5>Test5</entry5>
  <entry6>Test6</entry6>
  <!-- etc. -->
</root>
```

1. How is it possible to address a child element of a child element
   (3rd, 4th, etc. level)?
2. How is it possible to have all those child
   elements on one level (in resultlistEntries, in my example)?

Comment: Please post your expected output as code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the various `<entryX>` elements have nothing in common except that they all carry a text node, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root" >
    <root>
        <levelOne>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="levelOne/*"/>
        </levelOne>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[text()]" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! All the element names are known and the structure of the XML element is always the same.

Comment: @John I have edited my answer at the same time, because the output was not what you asked for. I still don't see a way to address all the <entryX> elements by name.